# Retrieving data from DB and display on JSF form

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I need ideas on how to proceed. I am implementing a Java web application using,

- Spring
- Hibernate
- JSF
- PrimeFaces

I have a form which is similar like a questionaire where user need to add their rating. The questionaire is as follows:

Question No  |  Description |  Self-Rating  |  Supervisor Rating

The self-rating and supervisor rating both are radio buttons. On selecting the radio button, it saves the rating in tbl_rating. The table structure is as follows:

tbl_rating:

RatingID |  QuestionID | Self_Rating |  Supervisor_Rating | Type   QuestionaireID

1. RatingID - Sequence Id generated by DB
2. QuestionID - Stores the question no
3. Self-rating - store self rating
4. Supervisor Rating - store supervisor rating
5. Type - Normally this questionnaire is filled twice a year (June and Dec) So type can be 'M' (Mid year) or 'E' (End of Year). While selecting the radio button, the type is set automatically.
6. QuestionaireID - Each questionaire is uniquely identified by this no.This Questionaire is used for both 'M' and 'E'

I don't have any issue on filling the questionnaire the first time. My problem is on edit mode. On clicking the edit button, the questionaire should have the values that the user has selected. Each record is identified uniquely by these 3 values QuestionID,Type,QuestionaireID. Below is part of my jsf code:

```
<p:row>
    <p:column colspan="1">1</p:column>
    <p:column colspan="2">Sample 1</p:column>
    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="8">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="self_rating" styleClass="selectRadio"
                          value="#{MyQuestionsComponent.question.self_rating}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{MyQuestionsComponent.ratingLists}" var="x" itemValue="#{x.code}" itemLabel="" />

            <p:ajax process="self_rating"
                    listener="#{MyQuestionsComponent.saveQuestionsRating('1',MyQuestionsComponent.question.self_rating,MyQuestionsComponent.question.questionaireId, 'self_rating','M')}" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="8">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="supervisor_rating" styleClass="selectRadio"
                          value="#{MyQuestionsComponent.question.supervisor_rating}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{MyQuestionsComponent.ratingLists}" var="x" itemValue="#{x.code}" itemLabel="" />

            <p:ajax process="self_rating"
                    listener="#{MyQuestionsComponent.saveQuestionsRating('1',MyQuestionsComponent.question.supervisor_rating,MyQuestionsComponent.question.questionaireId, 'supervisor_rating','M')}" />

        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

Below is my edit method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String editMyQuestion(Integer questionaireId) {
    Set<MyQuestion> tempList = myQuestionDAO.findQuestionRatingByQNO(Qno,"M");

    for(int i=1;i<50;i++){
        question = new Question();
        question=questionDAO.findQuestionRatingsByQuestionNo(Qno, "M", i);
    }
}
```

index i is currently the questionID which am passing. It set the whole questionaire with the last rating retrieve from the loop. It should assigned each questionId to respective rating.
Glad if someone can help me with this. I have to do it like this(Static).Give me some ideas on how to proceed. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ratingid?

Comment: No, this sequence is generated on saving a record in DB. It's a random number. How will i know this number in my edit method?

Comment: It will be created only once during insert, to edit existing rating aren't you reading it from DB first?

Comment: Ok on my form I have 5 Questions. I can retrieve all these 5 in a list. but how will I know which rating is for which question? Am confused..

Comment: each rating has questionID which will help correlate.